# Custom mail "bubbles" slows scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create bubbles, like in mail app on iphone. But a lot of bubbles (> 10) greatly slows scrolling of view.

Few words about my implementation: I create custom view and add "bubbles" on it. Here is how I create each "bubble":

```
...

self.gradient = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
self.gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:223.0f/255.0f 
                                                                      green:232.0f/255.0f 
                                                                       blue:247.0f/255.0f 
                                                                      alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                                                 (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0f/255.0f 
                                                                      green:207.0f/255.0f 
                                                                       blue:240.0f/255.0f 
                                                                      alpha:1.0f] CGColor], nil];
[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

// Border for "bubble"
[self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0f/255.0f 
                                           green:134.0f/255.0f 
                                            blue:214.0f/255.0f 
                                           alpha:1.0f].CGColor];    
[self.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
[self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

// Label for text of "bubble"
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[self.label setText:text];
[self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[self.label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
[self addSubview:label];

...
```

When I comment addition of gradient and border - everything works perfect!
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I was recommended to add next code, but it didn't increase performance.

```
[self.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[self.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

Comment: And you're creating them once then leaving the normal mechanisms to handle scrolling (eg, adding the view that ends up being `self` in the code quoted to a scroll view, letting the scroll view deal with everything from there)?

Comment: My guess is that either the gradients and borders are too expensive, or you are not reusing the "bubbles" (are you?). I posted an answer with a class I've used that draws those bubbles with Core Graphics. Check it out.

Comment: @Tommy Yes, exactly! I create them once.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, thanks a lot for link with class! I'll try it! Sorry, I didn't understand how can I reuse bubbles? If I use 30 bubbles, all of them should be on screen (in contrast to reusing of tableView cells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this class: https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell

It's pretty fast because it uses Core Graphics so it shouldn't slow your scrolling.